# Using Tweepy to get data from Topics in Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm not too familiar with Twitter's API, but I'm currently trying to utilize tweedy to pull specific tweets. I'm looking to pull tweets from the **trending tweets** topic, but I have not seen any endpoint in the tweepy docs or the twitter docs that specify how I can get all the tweets of a given topic.

Current code:

```py
import tweepy
from configs.twitter_config import TwitterConfig

class TweepyClient:
  client = None

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    
  def get_viral_tweets(self):
    query = "viral tweets"
    tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'geo', 'lang', 'public_metrics']

    result = self.client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, user_auth=True, tweet_fields=tweet_fields)
    return {
      'data': result.data,
      'next_token': result.meta['next_token']
    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
  twitter_config = TwitterConfig()
  api_key = twitter_config.get_api_key()
  api_secret = twitter_config.get_api_secret()
  access_token = twitter_config.get_access_token()
  access_token_secret = twitter_config.get_access_token_secret()

  client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=api_key,
    consumer_secret=api_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
  )

  tweepy_client = TweepyClient(client)
  viral_tweets = tweepy_client.get_viral_tweets()
  tweets = viral_tweets['data']
  print(tweets[0].public_metrics, tweets[0].text)
```

Wondering if there is anything I could possibly add to the `search_recent_queries` method, or if there is a method I missed that could accomplish this.

Side note: If no one else knows how to, I guess in theory I could follow from the base account and use it's feed as the viral posts topics?